# Return view with json object in MVC

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in MVC Controller that login the user. I need to return Json Object, so when it is successful it should redirect to another action(search action) otherwise it needs to stay is same page and show a login fail message. 
This is the Controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public JsonResult Login(LogInRequest logInRequest)
    {
        LogInResponse response = new LogInResponse();
        response.ReturnUrl = Url.Action  ("Search", "ContreollerName");             
 try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               .....
                if (logInRequest.UserName == "test")
                {
                    response.IsSuccessfull = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    response.IsSuccessfull = false;
                    response.ErrorDescription = MessageStrings.IncorrectUserName;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            response.ErrorDescription = MessageStrings.ServerError;
            response.IsSuccessfull = false;
        }
        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [Route("Search")]
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
     ......
        return View();
    }
```

in my view:

```
  @model CarFinance.Garage.Web.Models.LogInRequest
 <script src="~/Scripts/Login/login.js"></script>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "ContreollerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>UserName:</label></td>
            <td>
                <input name="UserName" type="text" placeholder="UserName" title="UserName" class="span_12" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Password:</label></td>
            <td>
                <input name="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password" title="password" class="span_12" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input id="btnLogin" type="submit" value="Log In" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

but anything I try it is returning the json object instead of view, I try to put some code in jquery but still it even does not to jquery method and just show screen like this:

```
{
 ReturnUrl: "/Search",
 IsSuccessfull: true,
 ErrorDescription: 
 ValidationErrors: [ ]
 }
```

I try to have some code in jquery but even it is not going in:

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function () {
alert("test");
```

.......

Comment: What's in `login.js`?

Comment: When you return json object,why you don't post your form with ajax?

Comment: Do not return a `JsonResult`. If the login is successful, redirect using `return RedirectToAction(,,,);` and if not, add a `ModelStateError` and return the view to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Login method returns only JSON data. So you should parse the response json and based on the `IsSuccessful` property value ,redirect to the new url

You need to make sure that your form is submitted via ajax. You can use jQuery `serialize` method along with `$.post` to do so.

```
$(function(){

    //Listen to the form submit event
    $("form").submit(function(e){
      // Prevent the default form submit behavior since we are doing ajax submit
      e.preventDefault();  

      //Get the url to which form should be submitted
      var url =$(this).closest("form").attr("action");
      //do an ajax post with serialized for data

      $.post(url,$(this).closest("form").serialize(),function(response){
          //Check the response and do needful.
          if(response.IsSuccessfull)
          {
             window.location.href=response.ReturnUrl;
          }
          else
          {
            alert("Login failed");
          }
      });   

    });
});
```

This should work assuming you do not have any other js code which is hijacking the form submit and there is no js errors in your page.

Comment: I think it's more than that, based on my reading.  It seems like the view code listed would do a normal post action via the browser and isn't invoking the login method via ajax or anything.  Thus explaining why the screen just shows JSON as a result.

Comment: @Shyju  but it even does not got to ajax as the alert is not showing.

Comment: I am updating the answer with the missing part. Hang on

Comment: Thanks @stephen.vakil. I updated the post to include details about making the form post ajaxified.